# Can Win32 API be dangerous to my computer?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to accidentally format the hard drive, damage the OS in some way when learning the Win32 API?

This question is an extension of the one asked here:

[Can learning C or C++ be dangerous to my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419041/can-learning-c-or-c-be-dangerous-to-my-computer)

The reason I ask is as follows.

Stupidly, I created an array of HWNDs but looped outside of its boundaries. When I ran the program, I noticed that windows in *other* programs on my desktop had been closed.

I don't believe I caused any damage to the computer or any other software, but cannot be sure.

Is this, or other form of mistake in Win32 API programming, dangerous to my computer/other software on the computer?

**EDIT:**
Apologies, when I say that windows in other programs had been closed, I should have said hidden, my loop was calling ShowWindow(..., SW_HIDE)

Comment: If you create a virtual machine and do your risky business in it, you won't have to worry about this. If you have Windows 7, [here's one explanation of how to do that](http://www.howtogeek.com/56158/beginner-how-to-create-a-virtual-machine-in-windows-7-using-virtual-pc/)

Comment: I find it disturbing that a modern OS let you do that.  What version of windoze are you running?

Comment: Basically, the only danger lies in accidently doing stuff you could do anyway, manually, like deleting your personal files, closing Word without saving the current document, etc. But that is hard to do unknowingly. As David says, if you are to do some `DeleteFile`, you need to write code that makes use of this function! Also, if you don't know exactly what you are doing, most likely your API calls will simply fail. Personally I have done a lot of 'sick' experiments using the Windows API, and never caused any unexpected problems. Windows is extremly robust. Really, no need to worry at all.

Comment: Considering the amount of code necessary to do even relatively simple things in the Win32 API, I'd say you're safer with it than say python ;-)

Comment: @CrazyEddie: Any modern OS will let you do things like that if you have the necessary privileges, and on the typical developer's machine, you most likely do.  I can easily wreak as much damage on an *IX machine as on a Windows machine with the same code.

Comment: @Carey That's not really accurate. I run my dev machines as a standard rights user due to UAC. So the OS limits what I can do.

Comment: @CareyGregory - the OP seems to be talking about one process violating the resources of another.  Even with admin rights that type of behavior is not allowed by most modern OS's.

Comment: +1, just for the title <g>

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then our experiences differ.  Most developers I know run as admin and turn UAC off on a routine basis, usually only running as a standard rights user for testing.  I do because I find UAC utterly annoying and time consuming.  I would much prefer the UNIX approach of having an su command when I need it.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Windows does prevent one process from violating the resources of another.  I was referring more to things like formatting a drive or deleting important files.

Comment: @CareyGregory Personally I never see the UAC dialog. Developers that turn it off, by and large, are just being arrogant. They think they are somehow superior. UAC? That's for users. But I'm a developer. Developing with UAC off is a sure fire way to introduce bugs to your program. Sure they should get picked up in the testing phase. But shouldn't you be testing all the time? Even whilst coding? Developers that think testing is work for other people are poor developers in my view.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No disagreement on developer testing, but how much of a pain UAC is depends a lot on what you're developing and what tools you use.  I get prompted all day long when I enable it.

Comment: @CareyGregory Maybe. What is it about your environment that results in lots of UAC dialogs?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm responsible for printing components on two products.  That includes print drivers, print processors, port monitors, and some system services.  So I'm frequently replacing system DLLs, starting/stopping services, modifying the registry, etc.  I do enable UAC for testing, but the time and hassle factor of having it enabled on a routine basis would outweigh the benefits I might gain from doing 100% of my testing and development with it enabled.

Comment: @CareyGregory OK, I can relate to your pain. In my case my team develops a simple desktop app. So we do have very different perspectives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty hard to do any real damage. You won't accidentally format a drive. The API calls needed to do that are pretty tricky to use. You can't call them successfully by accident.

You could pretty easily delete a bunch of files from the machine. But you'd need to be writing code that calling functions like `DeleteFile` to do that. In any case, so long as you have UAC enabled, the system security won't let you delete system files, or program files.

I don't think you need to worry unduly.

Comment: One problem is filling up the machine with files. "Leaking disk-space". E.g. Windows Update does that now and then.

Comment: Those errors are easy to resolve. No lasting damage is caused.